# Rewrite URL doesn't do anything

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm making a simple blog for my portfolio for school. If I click on a link to show a blogpost, my url is **domain.com/post?post_link=First-Post** I've read a hunderds of SO items about changing this url, but nothing works for me...

I hope that anyone see what is the problem and give a solution

---

I have 3 files, blog.php(Here are all the posts showed), post.php(Here is one blogpost showed, based on post tiltle from page before) and a .htaccess file.

My blog.php:

```
<form method="GET" action="post.php">
                    <input type="hidden" name="post_link" value="<?php echo $post_link;?>">
                    <input type="submit" name="">
                </form>
```

My post.php:

```
$post_link = $_GET["post_link"];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM blogposts WHERE post_link='$post_link'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    if ($result) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            $post_link = $row["post_link"];
        }
        echo $post_link;
    }
```

My .htaccess file:

```
Options FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^post/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)$ post.php?post_link=$1 
RewriteRule ^post/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/ post.php?post_link=$1 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

In addition to rewriting the url, everything works fine, like showing the posts and showing a single post

In blog.php, my input type hidden value is correct.

Please help..

Daniël

Comment: Your action is already post.php, you don't need to rewrite to it. You need to add a RewriteCond on the second rule, that excludes post.php

Comment: When I change the rewriterule to RewriteRule ^logi/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)$ post.php?post_link=$1 also nothing happend

Answer (score 0):

Change your action to just `post`

```
<form method="GET" action="post">
```

The resulting URL should be `localhost/takast/post?post_link=First-Post`

This Rule will then match this, but you need to keep the querystring `[QSA]`.

Complete .htaccess:

```
Options FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [QSA]
```

Comment: I have copied it into my .htaccess, but noting changed...Thank you in any case for your help

Comment: Ok. I can't see the full path in your example. post.php may not be the start of it. What's the full url to post.php?

Comment: The full path to post.php is http://localhost/takast/post.php , but then I get the error undefined index because my get variable isn't there

Comment: Everything is still the same. Only the post.php in the url is changed into post